# How to send and receive custom data with Phone through Bluetooth between close devices using Flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth, beacon

The interaction should be automatic: 
if a device enters in another device's area (or, if it is not possibile, they are in the same "region"), they send and receive a custom object (made of strings and ints).
So, there is no manual scanning or sending.
I looked at many libraries, but it seems impossibile to send custom data via Bluetooth and be in costant listening.

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: So, I realized it exists a way of broadcast sending and monitoring with two separate libraries. Now, I have to understand how to make my custom UUID. Maybe I could scan only for those who have the same layout or something (AltBeacons are new to me).

Comment: "there is no manual scanning or sending".  Do you *want* this to be impossible?  The question has many seemingly arbitrary constraints.  You can probably do something like this.  But you have to be flexible!

Comment: @davidgyoung I know that some libraries which automatically scan and send beacons, but it is restricted to iBeacon or AltBeacon. Unfortunately, those two Beacons could not be customized to send arbitrary data.

Comment: Sure they can. You just encode the data.  AltBeacon gives you 21 bytes to work with.  This is short, but it is about all you will get in a Bluetooth packet.  You can put whatever you want in those bytes, they are just numbers.  It is how you interpret them that matters.  But you do need to transmit on one side and scan on the other side.  If you can find flutter packages to let you both transmit and detect Bluetooth adverts this is straightforward programming.

Comment: See also my answer to your classmate here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930503/is-there-a-method-to-implement-in-flutter-a-sort-of-bluetooth-broadcast-like-bea. Can you please ask your professor to share his or her paycheck?

Comment: Thanks for your time.
Is there a way to scan or monitor for every beacon without a precise UUID?

Comment: On Android, yes.  Just specify the uuid as null   On iOS with iBeacon, no.  On iOS with AltBeacon, yes, just specify the uuid as nil.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Sorry for being pedantic, but, do you know by chance any library that allows to do so in Flutter Dart language?